# How to pass a value to a anonym method in Task.Factory

Tags: c#, parameters, parameter-passing, task, anonymous-function

I'm using a construct like that:

```
string myurl = "http://google.de";
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
   MessageBox.Show(url);
});
```

How to pass myurl to the anonym function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use it directly:

```
string myurl = "http://google.de";
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
   MessageBox.Show(myurl);
});
```

This is called a "closure".

If you don't want to do that then you can pass the url in as another parameter to `StartNew`:

```
string myurl = "http://google.de";
Task.Factory.StartNew(url =>
{
   MessageBox.Show((string)url);
}, myurl);
```

This second version is a tad more code, it limits you to only one parameter (so if you have several you need to either use a closure or put all of your parameters into some container object) and also types the parameter to `object`, thus forcing you to cast it to what it really is in the method body.  The advantage, on the other hand, is that there is a small overhead associated with closing over variables that you can potentially avoid using this method.  Note that in most situations this isn't going to be an important performance issue, so you should go with what is most convenient unless you have a reason to do otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. But one more question. Could there be problems (cross-threading), if the values are placed in GUI-Controls? Or do also closures solve this?

Comment: @netblognet You will get an error if you are trying to access a Control from a non-UI thread.  How you ensure that will vary based on the circumstances.

Comment: I know, that I'll get an error. ;) So when accessing data from controls in the above described example, I'll have to use the second example from your answer.

Comment: @netblognet If you want to get data from a control it's best to get the data out of the control before the call to `StartNew`, i.e. if you want the text of a textbox don't close over the textbox to get the text, get the text and store it in a string variable before calling `StartNew` and close over that string.